# Create a map entry in Clojure

Tags: clojure

What is the **built-in** Clojure way (if any), to create a single map entry?

In other words, I would like something like `(map-entry key value)`. In other words, the result should be more or less equivalent to `(first {key value})`.

Remarks:

- Of course, I already tried googling, and only found [map-entry?](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map-entry_q) However, this document has no linked resources.
- I know that `(first {1 2})` returns `[1 2]`, which seems a vector. However:

```
(class (first {1 2}))
; --> clojure.lang.MapEntry
(class [1 2])
; --> clojure.lang.PersistentVector
```

- I checked in the source code, and I'm aware that both [MapEntry](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/MapEntry.java) and [PersistentVector](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentVector.java) extend [APersistentVector](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/APersistentVector.java) (so `MapEntry` is more-or-less also a vector). However, the question is still, whether I can create a `MapEntry` instance from Clojure code.
- Last, but not least: "no, there is no built in way to do that in Clojure" is also a valid answer (which I strongly suspect is the case, just want to make sure that I did not accidentally miss something).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> "no, there is no built in way to do that in Clojure" is also a valid answer

Yeah, unfortunately that's the answer. I'd say the best you can do is define a `map-entry` function yourself:

```
(defn map-entry [k v]
  (clojure.lang.MapEntry/create k v))
```

Answer (score 6):

**Just specify a class name as follows**

```
(clojure.lang.MapEntry. "key" "val")
```

or import the class to instantiate by a short name

```
(import (clojure.lang MapEntry))

(MapEntry. "key" "val")
```

Answer (score 4):

As [Rich Hickey says here: "I make no promises about the continued existence of MapEntry. Please don't use it."](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/clojure/FVcrbHJpCW4/mDvIozL_qdwJ) You should not attempt to directly instantiate an implementation class such clojure.lang.MapEntry. It's better to just use:

```
(defn map-entry [k v] (first {k v}))
```

Comment: It was ten years ago! Apparently, Rich's plans changed since MapEntry still exists and even not deprecated https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/MapEntry.java. I think MapEntry class can be used freely if need.

Comment: Moreover, new factory method was added to the MapEntry class in 2015 https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/ae7acfeecda1e70cdba96bfa189b451ec999de2e/src/jvm/clojure/lang/MapEntry.java#L19-L21 which Rich Hickey uses in Clojure's sources, for instance here                                               https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/ae7acfeecda1e70cdba96bfa189b451ec999de2e/src/clj/clojure/core_deftype.clj#L215